# What is the purpose of `@ins << lambda` in this code?

Tags: ruby, lambda

In the first method listed below, the use method, it looks to me like :ins is an instance variable and attr is a method that provides getters and setters for :ins. What I'm not sure is what the `@ins << lambda` does.

```
module Rack
  class Builder
    attr :ins
    def use(middleware, *args, &block)
      middleware.instance_variable_set "@rack_builder", self
      def middleware.rack_builder
        @rack_builder
      end
      @ins << lambda { |app|
        middleware.new(app, *args, &block)
      }
    end

    def run(app)
      klass = app.class
      klass.instance_variable_set "@rack_builder", self
      def klass.rack_builder
        @rack_builder
      end
      @ins << app #lambda { |nothing| app }
    end

    def leaf_app
      ins.last
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@ins` is an instance variable which contains an Array.  Arrays support the operator `<<`, which appends an item to the end of the array.  For example: `[1, 2] << 3` results in `[1, 2, 3]`.  `lambda` is a [method which creates a Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005945).

So, to summarize: this code takes a block, creates a Proc out of it, and appends it to `@ins`.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is the array push operator. So this is pushing a lambda onto an array (or at least something array-like) called `@ins`.